# what happen you using put the ALTER statement in a transaction.?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I got a question about 
"What happens when you using Alter table command when a database is running?

is it possible to run the alter table when database is running? 
and if it's possible what will happen if you using alter table?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Some types of `ALTERs` respond 'instantly' as if nothing happened.  Some take a long time and block some or all activity on the table until the `ALTER` finishes.

What version of MySQL?  What was the `ALTER` statement?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.